# Mongodb: reverse document tree as a view (using C# driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying the following (simplistic scenario):

I have two documents that look like this (cinema has timeslots, timeslot has a movie):

```
{
   "_id":"5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c23",
   "Name":"Cinema 1",
   "TimeSlots":[
      {
         "Start":"2018-07-29T16:00:00.000Z",
         "End":"2018-07-29T18:30:00.000Z",
         "Movie":{
            "_id":"5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c24",
            "Name":"Movie 1"
         }
      },
      {
         "Start":"2018-07-29T15:00:00.000Z",
         "End":"2018-07-29T17:15:00.000Z",
         "Movie":{
            "_id":"5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c25",
            "Name":"Movie 2"
         }
      }
   ]
}

{
   "_id":"5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c26",
   "Name":"Cinema 2",
   "TimeSlots":[
      {
         "Start":"2018-07-29T18:00:00.000Z",
         "End":"2018-07-29T20:30:00.000Z",
         "Movie":{
            "_id":"5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c24",
            "Name":"Movie 1"
         }
      },
      {
         "Start":"2018-07-29T19:00:00.000Z",
         "End":"2018-07-29T21:15:00.000Z",
         "Movie":{
            "_id":"5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c25",
            "Name":"Movie 2"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I'd like to reverse the tree structure (so I have movies that have timeslots, which are linked to cinemas). In C# using LINQ I would do the following:

```
var movies = cinemas
    .SelectMany(cinema => cinema.TimeSlots)
    .Select(timeSlot => timeSlot.Movie)
    .Distinct(new MovieEqualityComparer())
    .Select(movie =>
    {
        movie.TimeSlots = cinemas
            .SelectMany(cinema => cinema.TimeSlots)
            .Where(timeSlot => timeSlot.Movie.Id == movie.Id)
            .ToList();

        return movie;
    })
    .ToList();
```

I'm wondering how one would achive this using the aggregate functions and a aggregate pipeline. I've tried several options including `$project`, `$unwind` and `$group` but I don't seem to be able to achieve the result I want. Any help is appriciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
[  
   {  
      $unwind:{ path:'$TimeSlots' }
   },
   {  
      $unwind:{ path:'$TimeSlots.Movie' }
   },
   {  
      $group:{ 
         _id:'$TimeSlots.Movie._id',
         movies:{  $addToSet:'$TimeSlots.Movie' } }
   },
   { $project: {  movieId: '$_id'} } }
]
```

Which results into a similar result of my LINQ query up until the distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use double `$unwind` here since you have only one movie per timeslot. You can try below aggregation:

```
db.cinemas.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$TimeSlots"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$TimeSlots.Movie._id",
            Name: { $first: "$TimeSlots.Movie.Name" },
            TimeSlots: {
                $push: { 
                    Start: "$TimeSlots.Start", 
                    End: "$TimeSlots.End", 
                    Cinema: { 
                        Name: "$Name", 
                        _id: "$_id" 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

which outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : "5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c25",
    "Name" : "Movie 2",
    "TimeSlots" : [
        {
            "Start" : "2018-07-29T15:00:00.000Z",
            "End" : "2018-07-29T17:15:00.000Z",
            "Cinema" : {
                "Name" : "Cinema 1",
                "_id" : "5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c23"
            }
        },
        {
            "Start" : "2018-07-29T19:00:00.000Z",
            "End" : "2018-07-29T21:15:00.000Z",
            "Cinema" : {
                "Name" : "Cinema 2",
                "_id" : "5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c26"
            }
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c24",
    "Name" : "Movie 1",
    "TimeSlots" : [
        {
            "Start" : "2018-07-29T16:00:00.000Z",
            "End" : "2018-07-29T18:30:00.000Z",
            "Cinema" : {
                "Name" : "Cinema 1",
                "_id" : "5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c23"
            }
        },
        {
            "Start" : "2018-07-29T18:00:00.000Z",
            "End" : "2018-07-29T20:30:00.000Z",
            "Cinema" : {
                "Name" : "Cinema 2",
                "_id" : "5b5dd8932dc7aa1e180f8c26"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I was still trying myself, and my solution was way more complicated! (the only thing I had figured out simiarly is the `Name: { $first: "$TimeSlots.Movie.Name" },`